# Azure Data Factory: Schema Change

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a blob with below format. First row gives header details and next 2 rows as data record and final row as trailer record which contains data records count. While record the file I want to define my schema as single field and once I remove my trailer record I want to convert it into proper schema format with "|" as delimiter. Could you let me know how can I achieve this please.

```
DeptID|DeptNAme
1|A
2|B
2
```

Thanks in Advance
Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update:**

1. After `SurrogateKey1` activity mentioned previously at Step4, we can use `Select` activity to select the column `DeptID|DeptNAme`.
   [image]
2. Then we can use `DerivedColumn1` activity, expressions `split({DeptID|DeptNAme},'|')[1]` and `split({DeptID|DeptNAme},'|')[2]` to generate new columns manually.
   [image]
3. The data preview is as follows:
   [image]

---

@Kumar G we can use [data-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/data-flow-create) in ADF to achieve that.
For example, I created a simple test.

1. I created a bolb in Azure Data Lake Gen2 as follows:
   [image]
2. I created a data source of this blob , select `Pipe (|)` as Column delimiter
   and  `First row as header`.
   [image]
   The schema is as follows:
   [image]
3. I created a mapping data flow in ADF and the source data preview is as follows:
   [image]
4. In `SurrogateKey1`, type in `Row_No` as Key Column, `1` as Start Value.
   [image]
   The data preview is as follows:
   [image]
5. In `Conditional split1`, use `Row_No < 3` to exclude the last line.
   [image]
6. In `Select1`, not select `Row_No` column,
   [image]
   The data preview is as follows:
   [image]

That's all!

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Your understanding is correct. Thought dataflow will fail as the trailer records format is not inline with data record format. Surprised it evaluated as NULL value for rest of the fields.. Thanks for your help.

Is there any option in ADF to read the whole record as one field and later tranform to propert schema format after deleting the trailer record?

Comment: Hi @Kumar G, I've updated my answer. Kindly let me know if you need more information. : )